# Getting PHP Catchable Fatal Error with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Why am I getting PHP Catchable Fatal Error with Laravel 5.1 when I try to run `php artisan`?

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\kinnect2\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\kinnect2\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 99

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<p>i think you used url() helper in your any config file in config folder, i had this same problem.</p>
<code>
        'highcharts' => [
            'styles' => [
                url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/highcharts.css'),
            ],
            'scripts' => [
                url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/highcharts.js'),
                url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/exporting.js'),
                url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/map.js'),
                url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/data.js'),
                url('bassets/plugins/highcharts/world.js'),
            ],
        ],
</code>
```

Comment: This is still an issue in Laravel 5.6 as of 11th June 2019. Thanks for the solve.